# What do I do to user data that is currently not verified?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql

Good day, I'm new to backend coding. What do I do to user data that did not confirm verification code from email during registration? Should I save it to database forever or do I have to delete it after a set of limited time when verified boolean is not met? I'm sorry if this is so beginner question.

Comment: By verify, do you mean logging in? If so you return some kind of status code usually a 401 status code.

Comment: I mean users did not enter the confirmation code from email what do I do with those??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up to you if this is a personal project. You could leave it in the database. doesn't hurt aside from taking up a row. If you wanted to make sure they verified themselves you could disable certain features till they verify other than that, you can leave them in the **DB** or Delete them after some time (make sure you have some paragraph in your privacy policy section stating that an account will be deleted if not verified after a certain number of days, months etc.). If you are trying to avoid unnecessary spam, then you can implement a **captcha**
This is a great thread that can help answer this question in more detail

https://www.indiehackers.com/post/what-do-you-do-with-unverified-users-e46f6cbe66